# Code within try is successfully executed but still facing exception from Catch part

Tags: java, selenium, exception, try-catch

I am trying to select values from dropdown using List,have already tried with Select but no luck.This code works fine for me but it is going within the Catch block too.

Here is the method for dropdown value selection using selenium .

```
public static void selectStatusFromDropDownInUserManagement(WebDriver driver, String testCasename, String Status) throws ActionBotException
     {
        String val = null;
        WebElement ele3 = null;

        try {

            ActionBot.click(driver, By.xpath(".//*[@data-id='status']"));

            WebElement ele=ActionBot.findElement(driver, By.xpath(".//*[@class='dropdown-menu open']/ul"));

            List<WebElement> columns= ele.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

            System.out.println(columns.size());
            for(WebElement ele2:columns)
            {
                ele3=ele2;
                val=ele2.getText();
                System.out.println(val);


            if(val.contentEquals(Status))
            {
                System.out.println("value from excel is"+Status);
                ele3.click();
            }

            }
            } catch (Exception e)
                {

            logger.info("Unable to select a status in user management page");

            ScreenShotUtil.takeScreenshot(driver, testCasename, "select Status 
            From Drop Down In User Management", false);
                    Assert.fail();
                }

                }
```

Comment: can you tell us, what exception you are getting?

Comment: If you find yourself in catch while debugging then this might be a debugger bug. Unless you are getting exception on the last line of code within `try-block`, in which case you should call `e.printStackTrace()` and post the stack trace here too.

Comment: As suggested, add a printStackTrace() to see what error you are getting. Most probably you are running through the loop, over some empty element after finding Status element which must be causing Exception, probably a NullPointer. Try adding a break after click(), guess that's all you want to do, click the element.

Comment: @Gautam adding break worked .Thanks!!